# Separate lists in markdown

Tags: list, markdown

It is possible to have two different list (one next to the other) in Markdown **without** an horizontal ruler?

- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3

---

- Elelemt 1
- Element 2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually use an HTML comment to break up adjacent lists, e.g.:

```
1. One
1. Two

<!-- -->

1. One
1. Two
```

On Stack Overflow, and just about everywhere else I've tried, this renders as

1. One
2. Two

1. One
2. Two

I think a comment is nicer than a `<br>` tag since it is semantically meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a pure markdown way, but most parsers will allow you to use a subset of HTML tags.

```
- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3


<br />


+ Elelemt 1
+ Element 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I use an empty link:

```
- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3

[]()

+ Elelemt 1
+ Element 2
```

It just renders as empty paragraph. It's easy to type (`[` `]` and `(` `)` are close to each other) and because `[]` is empty, it renders as a space between lists.

- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3

- Elelemt 1
- Element 2