# How to separate paragraphs containing unordered lists in markdown

Tags: markdown

I can write something like

```
Hello World

Test
```

to put the "Test" in a new paragraph. But when I have lists, suddenly this doesn't work anymore and the paragraphs are just combined into a single list:

```
- Hello
- World

- Test
```

results in:

- Hello
- World
- Test

I want "Test" to be separated from "Hello" and "World", with more space between them than is usually between two list items, because they are supposed to be separate lists that just happen to be in adjacent paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has already been answered here: [Separate lists in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210564/separate-lists-in-markdown), I didn't find that post when initially googling it.

Using the `<br>` tag seems to be a good way to force a line break, but I'm still not sure if that is supported by all markdown implementations. Also when rendered to HTML this probably generates a single paragraph with a break within it whereas the intent is to have two completely separate lists.